# How to stop Google Analytics Hacks?

Tags: google-analytics

What people are doing is basically taking the UA-XXXXXX code that you normally get with analytics, and they are generating calls against it. This is skewing my analytics stats. On top of that, in Google WebMaster tools, it's also causing this:

[image: People hacking my analytics stats]

It looks like somehow these pages, with my code on or at least with the generated code on, is making Google Webmaster tools think I have lots of 404's. This can't possibly be good for my rankings.

Anyone know if there is anything you can do to stop this?

Comment: This question belongs on http://webmasters.stackexchange.com/

Comment: Thank you! Do I delete it? Or just wait for someone to close it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you can filter by custom dimensions you can set a "token" in a custom dimension on every page and filter out any traffic in your view settings that does not include the token.

Obviously this will not help against people who use the code from your website (unless you also implement shahmanthan9s suggestion - which is a lot of work but will give you cleaner data), but it will work against drive-by shooters who randomly select UAIDs to send data to (which is the situation you refer to in your comment).

Answer (score 2):

Try making async call from your server end using CURL.That way you will never expose your GA code.
I have not implemented it, but it might work as per theory

Comment: Very interesting concept, but I don't think they know what my code is. I think they have a generator that runs calls against 1, then 2, then 3 and so forth. So even if I get a new code, eventually they will guess it.

Comment: Yes that right, but you will be have your GA CURL calls only on pages which are available and not on 404 Pages. This way you can prevent brute- force that is being done on website. That reminds me you can block a particular IP that is spamming your website temporary or permanently.